# bash: how to make smarter auto-complete on tab press

Tags: command-line, bash, git

Using the `git status` command, I had:

```
modified:   conf/test.conf
```

Is it possible to configure bash in that way so when I type `git diff *test.conf` and press TAB for auto-complete, it would expand it to full path. i.e: `conf/test.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a [git](/questions/tagged/git) nor a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) expert, but this works for me:

```
git diff *$(file="$(git status -s)"; echo ${file:2})
```

I haven't tested yet with multiple pending files or multiple directories, but you can change and use these to work mostly like a shortcut to your file/directory.

For using the TAB key in the terminal, I don't think there's an easy way to change the terminal keys behavior based on the running command (Someone correct me if I'm wrong).